# Way to find the elements from the html code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have these details on a website that I need to automate:

PROPERTY DETAILS

```
Zip:10001
Neighborhood:Midtown
City:New York City
State:NY
```

This is the html deatils of the city for example:

```
<div class="row propertyDetailsRow margin-bottom-10px ng-scope" ng-if="property.City != null">
   <strong style="margin-right: 10px;">City:</strong>
   <span class="ng-binding">New York City</span>
</div>
<strong style="margin-right: 10px;">City:</strong>
<span class="ng-binding">New York City</span>
```

Is there any way I can find the element City and the element New York City in order to use them in my code?
I need to find the lhs elements and  the value that is written next to them.
For example City and the value is New York City.
Is there any way to get the details of the elements from this html?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried findElementByXpath?

Comment: what did you already tried ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPATH. Install a tool like FirePath to help yourself debug this, then probably try this:

"//div[contains(text(), 'City:')]//span"

or try this

//div[contains(@class,'row propertyDetailsRow margin-bottom-10px ng-scope')]//span[@class='ng-binding']

Comment: i tried with findElementByXpath but i always get the following error no matter what attribute I use: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(text(),’City:’]//span' is not a valid XPath expression